# how to obtain station uptime(start time) information in Niagara-4?

Tags: niagara-4

1. I am trying to get the start time of niagara station.
2. I see there is a Sys Class that provides singleton to access all the functionality.
3. i want to get the start time of the station and i am unable to find a property that would result in that.
4. I can see in resourcemanager and when spied on station to see there is start time information there but i am not able to retrieve it.
   i access those information by going to following ords:

> ```
>     local:|foxs:|spy:/sysInfo
>     local:|foxs:|view:chart:ResourceManager
> ```

code i have been playing with:

```
Sys.getStation().getSysInfo().getFacets()
```

the sysinfo facets looks empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the static field Nre.bootTime, which is set to System.currentTimeMillis() when the station starts, and then subtract it from "now" in order to obtain the uptime - something like this:

```
import com.tridium.sys.Nre;
import javax.baja.sys.BRelTime;

long uptimeMilliseconds = BAbsTime.now().getMillis() - Nre.bootTime;
  
BRelTime uptime = BRelTime.make(uptimeMilliseconds);
  
System.out.println("Uptime:");
System.out.println(uptimeMilliseconds + " ms");
System.out.println(uptime);
```